# Not all rows are imported from Excel file using OPENROWSET in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, openrowset, aceoledb

I have a Excel table with 47 columns and 14K rows. I import this data to SQL Server with `OPENROWSET`:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.my_table
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET
(
    'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\ExcelFile.xlsx',
    'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'
);
```

However, only 5138 rows were imported. After some time the number of imported rows decreased down to 5052, i.e. every time - different number of rows.
However, when I use `Tasks -> Import Data...`, then *all* rows are successfully imported.
What's the reason of such behavior?

I'm using SQL Server 2017 14.0.3356.2.

Comment: Is there, by any chance, a gap in the data in  your spread sheet (i.e. a blank row)?

Comment: @Larnu No. There are no gaps. As I noted, `Import Data` worked just fine. It means `OPENROWSET` should work just fine, too.

Comment: @JohnyL If you can add sample data, it would be easier to understand your problem.

Comment: @droebi The data is sensitive, but I will try to replace it with dummy values.

Comment: You may want to add IMEX=1 to your connection string. IMEX=1 allows data to be read with mixed types (text) any other value of IMEX will read the first 8 rows to determine the type of the column, then any rows which don't match that type are ignored. See https://jingyangli.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/imex1-revisit-and-typeguessrows-setting-change-to-0-watch-for-performance/

Comment: @JohnyL have you already created sample data that can be used for testing?

Comment: @SteveFord SteveC's answer did the trick - the problem was with syntax, although one more thing had to be done (see my comment). Anyway, thanks for answer!

Comment: Great!  Thank you, glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the SQL Server code differs slightly from the example code in the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#openrowset). To exactly conform to the syntax of the code in the Docs it should look something like this

```
INSERT INTO dbo.my_table
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET
(
    'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\ExcelFile.xlsx',
    [Sheet1$]
);
```

The name of the sheet [Sheet1$] is no longer inside quotes and the SQL-like code ("SELECT * FROM ") was removed.

The other possible issue could be with specifying HDR=Yes.  Do each of the columns for which there is/are any rows have a header without spaces and/or unusual formatting?  It's something to consider if needed.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I will give it a try!

Comment: After some tests your code did work, but in order to work, I had to set `AllowInProcess=1` and `DynamicParameters=1` for `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider. Only after that *all* rows were imported successfully! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I guess, you need to mention setting those parameters in your answer. Thanks! 